# Syncing db-data between developers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

We're two developers utilizing Git in development of a Rails app.

How do we share stored data in the development-database between eachother?

In development we're using SQLite3 and in production PostgreSQL.

Comment: can't you use a shared database?

Comment: You mean to share development.sqlite3 in app/db? 

(I understand know that my questions wasn't clear enough that I meant in dev env and not the production db.)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if your production DB is in Postgresql, then your dev environment should also have Postgresql.

Have a common instance of Postgresql running and both the dev's can connect to the same instance.

Comment: I know, ideally. But the amount of headache pg has given me doesn't make it worthwhile. The phase we're in isn't demanding super high performance from the db, just in need of something that works.